Is it possible to access Google Analytics of this section?
As you probably know, to spread websites, SEO (search engine optimization) is a powerful tool.
It could be really helpful to have some information about the most searched phrases on this section to use specific terms and make the titles more friendly to search engines.

Moderators have access to such information, but are specifically forbidden from sharing it.
More importantly, our goal should not be SEO, but generating quality answers and asking careful questions that we are seriously thinking about and have done initial research for.
Also, it is my opinion (although not a universally shared one) that our goal shouldn't be to spread this SE to the internet at large, but to target experts. SEO is not the best way to get the attention of experts, maintaining a higher caliber of content and personal introduction to the site is the way.

A really interesting answer. I wrote this question after searching for a Medicine section on SE and finding out that, with my big surprise, it was closed.. So I thought that if this section should risk the same end I would be very sad about that. However I agree and appreciate your ideas.

@Revious you are pretty new to this SE, I advise exploring it a bit before you get too worried about its future. Do note that any self-help or prescription-related questions are off-topic for our site; i.e. medical advice is not allowed here (either in answers or questions).

yes, I know they are forbidden. You are right, no need to worry. ps: about medic advice maybe I've expressed in a bad way and I've been misunderstood. I was speaking of this section http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it

In addition to Artem's points, every page has a view count. In general, over time, most traffic for most pages comes from Google searches. Thus, you can get a sense of what content proved to be popular by looking at view counts.
For example, you could look at questions that have over 2,500 views. 
I would not specifically ask questions to maximise views. That said, a few general principles might flow from an analysis of popular questions. My own feeling is that good editing is important. In particular, clear and descriptive titles are particularly important as these are likely to be highlighted in search results.
